# Ruby - is there a shorthand check for two logical conditionals against one variable

Tags: ruby

How can I shorten this expression?

```
if artist != 'Beck' && artist != 'Led Zeppelin'
  5.times { puts 'sorry' }
end
```

Is there a shorthand check for two logical conditionals against one variable?

---

As an aside, this turned into

```
class String
  def is_not?(*arr)
    !arr.include?(self)
  end
end
```

In our project.

Now we can do `'foo'.is_not?('bar', 'batz')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unless ['Beck', 'Led Zeppelin'].include?(artist)
  5.times { puts 'sorry' }
end
```

Isn't any "shorter", but no obscure syntax trickery too. Just using regular array api. As a consequence, you can provide that array in any way you want. Load it from a file, for example. With any number of elements.

Comment: ...or  `5.times { puts 'sorry' } unless ['Beck', 'Led Zeppelin'].include?(artist)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: personally, I'd rather not. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your specific case is pretty minimal, but if you have lots of unrelated conditions to test for lots of values you can set the tests up as lambdas in an array and use `all?`.  For instance, the following example filters all the integers between 1 and 100 for those which are > 20, < 50, even, and divisible by 3:

```
tests = [
  ->(x) { x > 20 },
  ->(x) { x < 50 },
  ->(x) { x.even? },
  ->(x) { x % 3 == 0 }
]

(1..100).each do |i|
  puts i if tests.all? { |test| test[i] }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case artist
when 'Beck', 'Led Zeppelin'
else
  5.times { puts 'sorry' }
end
```

Comment: While this is producing the same side-effects, it is a misuse of case/when, don't you think? :)